# “setTimeout is not defined” when using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I get a "setTimeout is not defined" error returned whenever I run this code, whats wrong with it? I know its probably a stupid mistake i'm making...
the npc. are specific to the program im running this code in, the script itself is separate from any html code

```
var time = Math.floor((world.getTime() % 24000) / 10);
npc.say(time);
if (time == 1195) {
  npc.say("I need some rest");
  //npc.navigateTo(-724,60,782,1.0);
  npc.setHome(-724,60,782);
  npc.setAnimation(2);
}
else if (time == 2385) {
  npc.setAnimation(0);
  //npc.navigateTo(-734,68,769,1.0);
  npc.setHome(-734,68,769);
  npc.say("Time to tend the crops");
  while (time != 1194){
      npc.say(time);
      var randum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
      if (randum == 1) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              npc.say("1");
              npc.setHome(-734,67,768);
          },5000); 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about about setTimeout but you have an infinite loop there.

Comment: `timeout` inside infinite `while`, the variable `time` is not changed causing the while to go in infinite loop

Comment: The variable `time`, constantly changes by itself, does that not mean that the while loop isn't infinite?

Comment: What environment is this in? `setTimeout` is defined as a global in all browsers and NodeJS. If this is in some other environment, check that environment's documentation.

Comment: @RustyJP: That depends on the environment. In most traditional JavaScript environments (browsers and NodeJS), the code is run single-threaded, and nothing can modify your `time` variable. But in a multi-threaded environment like the JVM, sure, `time` could be volatile, provided you really do share it between threads.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do they have jvm for javascript? Its interesting. Could you name it? Just want to know more about it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Is there a way I can remove the setTimeout, but still have a delay at the end of the if statement?

Comment: @xyz: Oracle's JVM runs JavaScript, it's part of the JDK, added when they added scripting support. In fact, there are *two* JavaScript engines for the JVM from Oracle: Rhino and the newer Nashorn (that's "nass-horn", German for...Rhino).

Comment: @RustyJP: **Again**: What environment is this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: All I know is that its a ECMA script inside minecraft, running  as part of the Custom NPCs mod, I know that probably doesn't help sorry. The `time` variable gets updated by minecraft automatically and so is changing constantly

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your while loop looks like it's causing a problem. It's stuck in an infinite loop.

Try removing the while loop for debugging and see if your setTimeout error still happens:

example:

```
else if (time == 2385) {
  npc.setAnimation(0);
  //npc.navigateTo(-734,68,769,1.0);
  npc.setHome(-734,68,769);
  npc.say("Time to tend the crops");
  // while (time != 1194){ -- commenting out for debugging!
      npc.say(time);
      var randum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
      if (randum == 1) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              npc.say("1");
              npc.setHome(-734,67,768);
          },5000); 
     // }
  }
}
```

If that fixes the problem, you'll want to consider how to update the time inside of the while loop, so eventually you'll break out of it.

I made a sample jsfiddle for you to try http://jsfiddle.net/qanzdm8g/7/. This should allow you to try different things and see what works!